# referring to the sole of foot and other same positions

Tags: meaning

Which of the below sentences are correct and better to use in informal English language?

> A) Under my right foot is terribly itching.
>
> B) My right underfoot is terribly itching.
>
> C) The sole of my right foot is terribly itching?

And what if the position I was going to refer to was somewhere rather than my feet?

> D) I have a painful pimple *under(?)* my right thigh.
>
> E) A green chewing gum had stuck to the ...(back? / bellow? / underneath? / bottom? / none?) of my seat in the cinema.

In the last sentence please note that it's not talking about the backrest, rather it's talking about where you put your buttock.

Comment: None of your first three examples are idiomatic. They are "correct", but they will sound silly to any native English speaker. In these sentences, we would not use the adverb before the verb. In the second question (you're supposed to ask only one, by the way) we would use a noun like _bottom_ or _underside_, and never a preposition like _below_.( Also, _"bellow"_ is the sound made by an enraged water buffalo. This is a different word than the preposition. Always use an English language dictionary to be sure you are spelling words correctly. One small letter can make a large difference.)

Comment: A-C, "the *bottom/sole* of my right foot". D, "on my right thigh" (you can add front/back of), E, "to the bottom of" or "underneath".